# Nested Loop For loop with two inner for loop in PHP

Tags: php, loops, nested

I require a nested `for` loop for my php website which gives me results as follows.

I want to two integers incrementally - one stops at 12 and other continues until the specified values.

If one string is `$i` and second string is `$j` than I want output as:

```
        $i  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10   11   12
        $j  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10   11   12
        $i  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10   11   12
        $j  13 14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21   22   23   24
        $i  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10   11   12
        $j  25 26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33   34   35   36
```

It should be repeated up to `n` values.

Comment: I can understand what you want to accomplish. I don't think you need to nest two loops, one will be enough. What code have you written so far? What problem did you encounter?

Comment: `this is my first question `...but you haven't asked a question or described a problem. (Hint: "how to write this" is too broad / vague, before you rush for the "edit" button.). Take the [tour] and read [ask]. You're expected to show some attempt to research and implement your requirement yourself, and then explain to us precisely where you got stuck. We'll _help_ you with _your_ code, but we're not here to do all the thinking and coding for you. And we don't give out tips, tutorials, designs, part-solutions, pseudo-code etc - we don't know your level of expertise to be able to explain clearly

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: i make a online software for a company in witch i want to generate pdf by mpdf in this connection i want to put a block of data in 1st page with 12 block and in next page 12 block id remain same but data id is increased with 12 +1 in second page. so i only ask a question for one string increased upto 12 while other string increased up to data row in mysql table please help me

Comment: You still haven't asked a question or described a problem. "I want" isn't a question or problem statement. You're also expected to show some attempt to solve your problem yourself, and then ask us when you get stuck. It's not clear where you're stuck - all you've done is list some requirements, and a very vague description of what part you need help with. We are _not_ a free write-my-code service. We're volunteers spending our free time...we'll help you if you showed you also spent reasonable time on it first. You can [edit] your question when you have more info for us.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<?php
createMatrix(40);

function createMatrix($jMax)
{
    $jVal = 0;

    while ($jVal < $jMax) {

        // print line $i
        echo ('$i' . "\t");
        for ($iVal = 1; $iVal <= 12; $iVal++) {
            echo "$iVal\t";
        }
        echo "\n";

        // print line $j
        echo ('$j' . "\t");
        for ($j = 1; $j <= 12; $j++) {
            $jVal++;
            echo "$jVal\t";
            if ($jVal === $jMax) {
                echo "\n";
                break;
            }
        }
        echo "\n";
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You can remove one `for` loop if you store the result of the loop in strings, instead of echoing it directly. However, even though your code accurately reproduces what is shown in the question, I doubt this answer is useful. For one, you don't explain your code. You're not actually helping to solve a problem, you're doing an assignment for a student. What can this student learn from your answer? Ask, and then copy the answer, is better than learning to solve problems yourself? Remember, this is a very simple assignment, which almost anybody with a bit of knowledge of PHP can do.

Comment: In most cases we learn from example code, aren't we? I just wanted to help...

Comment: @SiL3NC3 we learn from example code yes, but that requires an explanation of the code to be provided. Otherwise for someone who doesn't fully understand it, it might not be clear what is intended, or what each of the parts is doing. So if you want to help, you should edit your answer with more info :-).